# How do I publish a template in such that it display on specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I have created a navigation menu template and i want it to display only in pages that are meant for logged_in users. How do i achieve that please[image]

Answer (score 0):

Singular > pages > and then look the page by typing the title. If it's more than one add a new condition for each page.

If you have a global template also make sure to add exclude condition for the same pages in it too.

[image: display options]